# Is there any advantage to waxing vinyl siding?

Tags: vinyl-siding

My 20+ year old siding can get pretty moldy and grimy in one year. I wondering if waxing it, after I clean it, would help reduce the mold and dirt accumulation and give it new life. I see car waxes that say they can be used for waxing vinyl siding.

Comment: I would say the biggest advantage is if you have a tournament coming up against the Cobra Kai.

Comment: LOL. Ok, maybe a spray type wash and wax formula, not a paste wax.

Comment: Waxing usually has to be done less often then shaving.

Comment: What kind of cleaner/wax did you use on your vinyl siding?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We use a cleaner/Wax, with a polyurethane base.  /  formulated from concentrate. We venture the material from the container through our power washer, using a wax/cleaner nozzle in our wand. its usually a one step cleaning, and the poly base fills the tiny pits in the siding caused by exposure to the elements. your finish is smoothened  with a poly-glow effect.  This protection prevents mold/as the surface is sealed. houses in worse than normal condition, gets 2 applications.  After treatment, the finish is much like a newly waxed vehicle, and the water beads, and runs off, with a dry shine. usually after proper application, it only needs spraying with garden hose to refresh luster.  Every 3-5 years, you can expect to re-apply.